# How do I display Button in Nifty GUI without XML?

Tags: java, slick2d, nifty-gui

I'm trying to make a GUI for my game. I've tried various libraries and I've ended up with Nifty. I haven't found any useful tutorial and therefore I'm learning from code examples.

I want to display a simple `Button`, but it seems that my code is not working. I've tried setting background color of `Panel` which has been working. I have no idea why the `Button` is not displaying.

Here's what I have:

```
protected void prepareNifty(Nifty nifty) {
    ScreenBuilder sb = new ScreenBuilder("start");
    LayerBuilder lb = new LayerBuilder();
    PanelBuilder pb = new PanelBuilder();

    pb.control(new ButtonBuilder("btn1", "First Button!"){{
        alignCenter();
        valignCenter();
        height("5%");
        width("15%");
        backgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }});

    pb.childLayoutCenter();
    lb.childLayoutVertical();
    lb.panel(pb);
    sb.layer(lb);

    nifty.addScreen("start", sb.build(nifty));
}
```

I should add I'm using Slick2D and my class extends `NiftyBasicGame`.

How can I display the `Button` and set it an absolute position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to load the controls and the styles too when you want to use the default controls, like the Button control.

Try something like:

```
nifty.loadStyleFile("nifty-default-styles.xml");
nifty.loadControlFile("nifty-default-controls.xml");

new ScreenBuilder("start") {{
  layer(new LayerBuilder("background") {{
    backgroundColor("#f008");
    childLayoutAbsolute();
    control(new ButtonBuilder("showPopupButton", "SHOW") {{
      x(SizeValue.px(100));
      y(SizeValue.px(100));
      interactOnClick("showPopup()");
    }});
  }});
}}.build(nifty);
nifty.gotoScreen("start");
```

Besides that, it might help to read the [nifty-gui-the-manual-1.3.2.pdf](https://github.com/void256/nifty-gui/raw/1.4/nifty-core/manual/nifty-gui-the-manual-1.3.2.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to load the controls. Do I need to load the styles? For example, if I want to set only white background and nothing else, like I'm doing in my question.

Comment: Yes, you'll need the styles too. Without styles there is no button :)